# What is the standard Apple blue colour?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicolor

Historic question.

the information is now available in UIKit:

**UIColor.systemBlue**

---

How to access / use the standard Apple blue color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since iOS 7, you can simply use this:

```
UIColor.systemBlue
```

Answer (score 44):

A bit late, but you can find the colour values in Apple's [Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/color/).

The blue is `(R, G, B) = (0, 122, 255) = #007AFF`

[image: Apple colours]

I created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/DavidRysanek/fcca558c27e4e7b7d89d88b1fabeb4f1) with UIColor extension for your convenience.

Comment: link is broken now :(

Comment: Hmmm.... It works for me even in anonymous browser. Perhaps you have too strict networking policy?

Answer (score 11):

Try the digital color meter? It seems to think (14, 122, 254).

[image]

Then add a category:

```
@implementation UIColor (MyColors)

+ (UIColor*)appleBlue {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255 green:122.0/255 blue:254.0/255 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Comment: In DigitalColor Meter, go to View > Display Values > As Percentage.  No need to divide by 255 :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking just for the RGB hexcode, here it goes:

'#0E7AFE'

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: I think I can't with my rank (21).

Comment: note that the hexcode given in the user interface doco is 007AFF ... the only really correct answer now is UIColor.systemBlue

Comment: I'm using in my apps the color ''#0E7AFE'' and seems to be fine. But I'll try '007AFF' to see if it is better.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for swift:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func appleBlue() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 14.0/255, green: 122.0/255, blue: 254.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```